# Ler Dados de um ficheiro .csv e passar valores da linha para Tuplo

Tags: python, csv, tuple

Os dados no ficheiro cidades.csv estão organizados da seguinte forma:

Lisboa,Madrid,600

Madrid,Paris,650

```
import csv
with open('cidades.csv', 'r') as f: # Somente r para leitura do arquivo
      list1 = [tuple(line.values()) for line in csv.DictReader(f)]
```

Como faço para ler os valores para cada tuplo da lista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você precisa converter um csv para um dicionário, seu código está correto então, vou usar ele como base para resposta. Quando você usa `csv.DictReader` ele cria um dicionário baseado nas chaves e valores de cada coluna. Por exemplo:

Primeira linha do csv:

```
| Nome | Telefone | Cidade |
```

E as linhas consequentes com os valores

```
| Manoel  | 999999999 | Lisboa    |
| Eduardo | 888888888 | São Paulo |
```

Quando a função `DictReader` for aplicada a esse csv, ele vai nos retornar um iterável e cada elemento da lista vai ser um dicionário com as chaves do valores:

```
{'Cidade': 'Lisboa', ' Nome': ' Manoel', 'Telefone': '999999999'}
{'Cidade': 'São Paulo', ' Nome': ' Eduardo', 'Telefone': '888888888'}
```

Usando como base o teu código, temos algo bem parecido com o que desejas, vamos lá:

```
import csv
with open('arquivo.csv', 'r') as f: # Somente r para leitura do arquivo
    ler = csv.DictReader(f)
    for linha in ler:
        # Cada linha aqui, já um dicionário completo, porém, se precisar
        # transformar o mesmo em uma tupla pode usar dict.values()
        print(tuple(linha.values()))
```

O que vai retornar algo parecido com isso:

```
('Lisboa', ' Manoel', '999999999')
('São Paulo', ' Eduardo', '888888888')
```

Comment: sim mas eu quero armazenar esses Tuplos todos numa lista para depois eu usar o atributo "distancia" para calcular o menor caminho entre duas cidades

Comment: É só no lugar de printar, inserir em uma lista

Comment: tenho algo assim:    list1 = [tuple(line.values()) for line in csv.DictReader(f)]

Comment: list1 = [tuple(line.values()) for line in csv.DictReader(f)]                              para aceder a cada indice do tuplo como faço